# <div> disappearing when page resized and <article> not resizing properly

Tags: html, css

I'm creating my first website but I've ran into two problems. You can view the page and my code [here](http://codepen.io/attkom/pen/wMPZOx?editors=110).

1. There is `<div id="topLine"></div>` under the header that is 2px tall and stretches the entire width of the browser/ viewport. This div disappears when the browser is resized to a smaller height (so you probably won't see it on the codepen page I linked to). I want it to always look like this: [website header with horizontal line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpDc9.png). I've tried changing z-index and using different positioning but I can't seem to keep it from disappearing.
2. The `<article>` does not expand vertically to the bottom of the page. The text expands vertically past the container. I've tried using different positioning but I can't make it stretch to the bottom of the page.

I get this problem using Chrome 47, IE 11, and Edge 20 - so it doesn't seem to be a browser specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100vh;
}

article {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxYEBw

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem with `#topline` is `html`'s `height: 100%;` and `body`'s `height: 100%;`. Height fixing using `100%` is really tricky.
2. The problem with `article` is its `height: 100%;` (again - tricky). Once removed it works just fine for me.

After removing both of them you will have some problems with other `height` properties. Due to that you will need to check all of them (sadly).

[Height property at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp)

You can workaround `#topline` with `border` property instead of making its background orange.

You can easily extend `article` to the bottom with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For

(1) - Put the contents of the header into a DIV, then make the header 100% and put a border under it.

```
<header>
    <div>
        <img id="logo" src="http://arkelectronics.ca/arkLogo.png" alt="Logo">
        <h1>ARK Electronics</h1>
    </div>
</header>

header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:2px solid orange;
}
header>div{width:600px;margin:0 auto;}
```

(2) For the `<article>`, just remove the height (or set to auto).

Revised pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQaNNL

Comment: You are missing a </header> by the way

Answer (score 0):

```
#topLine {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: orange;
position:absolute;/*here past postion*/
}


article {
  background-color: #ededed;
  width: 600px;
  height: ;  /*delete height */
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-left: 5px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-right: 5px solid #f6f6f6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to just do two changes.
First would be to change the position of the #topline to absolute.

```
#topline{
position:absolute;
}
```

and second would be to change the article height to auto. Because height:100% is only making its height 100% until the page loads for the first time. But when you start scrolling it does not scale back.

```
article{
height:auto;
}
```

Do the changes and you will be fine.